# How to apply Css class to a row using datatables.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I have retrieved table from SQL procedure contains column with name of class that is to be applied on that particular row.
However that table is passed to datatable.js as a data-source.
Now with my code, specified class is getting applied to only one cell: in `fnRowCallback()` function.
I want is to apply that class to entire row.

### Here is my `javascript` code:

```
var dataSet = JSON.parse("[" + a.toString() + "]")    
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#demo').html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>');

    $('#example').dataTable({
        "data": dataSet,                
        "columns": [
                        { "title": "Center" },
                        { "title": "Call Executive" },
                        { "title": "Name" },
                        { "title": "Mobile" },
                        { "title": "Phone" },
                        { "title": "Status" },
                        { "title": "Appt Date" },
                        { "title": "Joined Date" },
                        { "title": "Remark" },
                        { "title": "Source" },
                        { "title": "Publisher" },
                        { "title": "css" },
                      ]
                      ,
        "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
            if (aData["css"] == "gradeC") {
                $(nRow).addClass('gradeC');
            }
            else {
                $(nRow).addClass('gradeN');
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Sample Datatable string (class is specified in last column) passed to function is:

```
    var dataSet = ['Dadar', 'lmsSenitaD', 'Atul salaskar', '9876543210', '', 'Not Joined', '10/01/2014', '', 'Come back and Join', 'Mobile', 'Times','gradeC'],
['Aundh', 'Rashmi', 'Preeti Gupta', '9876543210', '', 'Not Joined', '10/01/2014', '', 'Will Discuss with Family', 'Online Campaign', 'Iksula','gradeN'],
['Do@Home_Thane', 'Rashmi', 'Mitali Gupta', '9876543210', '', 'Joined - Old Date', '10/01/2014', '20/08/2014', 'Come back and Join', 'Online Campaign', 'Iksula','gradeC'];
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code in `fnRowCallback` so the problem must be in the data.  Can you add `Console.log(aData['css'])` to confirm that the correct data is returned?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem comes from what you think you get in `aData`. When the `fnRowCallback` callback is called `aData` is not an object with the key corresponding to the column titles. It is just the data (array) corresponding to that row. Exactly the same arrays as the one you passed in the `dataSet`. So, if you want to get the `css` column you need to know the index of that column in you array. It seems easy in your case because it happens to be the last one. So you can do something like this to get the css class name:

```
"fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
    var css = aData[aData.length - 1];
    if (css == "gradeC") {
        $(nRow).addClass('gradeC');
    }
    else {
        $(nRow).addClass('gradeN');
    }
}
```

Or if you want to apply whatever class contained in the css column:

```
"fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
    $(nRow).addClass(aData[aData.length - 1]);
}
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/828pu5tL/).

Comment: You got exact Answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the DataTables createdRow event to add a class (just as their example, except you would add the class in one of the row's fields)

See http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html for an example

The value for that specific row can be gotten from the data array. 
For example, if the class is in column 5, add the class to the row

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
            $(row).addClass(data[5]);
        }
    } );
} );
```

Comment: In this question, Class is retrieved from JS string only. Then how to apply that, using your suggestion... Mention clearly please!

Answer (score 0):

If it were pulling from a database the data would have a primary key, and therefore just use getElementbyId and apply the appropriate styling

```
document.getElementById("dataSetID")
```